# ¿Cómo aplicar estilo a un item hijo específico?

Tags: css, html5, css3

Tengo el siguiente código, solo que nth-child() no es compatible en algunos browsers, además de ello, no puedo asignar una clase para diferenciarla, pues, estoy modificando solo estilo sin alterar el html.

```css
ul > li:nth-child(2){
   color:red; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="clase-1">
        <div class="clase-2">
            <div class="clase-3">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li>Elemento 1</li>
                    <li>Elemento 2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cómo hacer para aplicar estilo sólo al segundo li sin usar nth-child dado que es incompatible con algunos browsers?

Comment: Y los browsers que se usarán son realmente incompatibles? Aquí puedes revisar la [compatibilidad con las versiones de los browsers que permiten usar nth-child](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_nth-child).

Comment: Lo digo por lo que acabo de experimentar, en Opera me funciona muy bien, en Chrome y en Safari no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar una clase de esta forma:

```css
.red{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="clase-1">
        <div class="clase-2">
            <div class="clase-3">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li>Elemento 1</li>
                    <li class="red">Elemento 2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tambien puedes usar un identificador:

```css
#red{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="clase-1">
        <div class="clase-2">
            <div class="clase-3">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li>Elemento 1</li>
                    <li id="red">Elemento 2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tambien puedes meter el elemento 2 en un span y llamar a este:

```css
span{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="clase-1">
        <div class="clase-2">
            <div class="clase-3">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li>Elemento 1</li>
                    <li><span>Elemento 2<span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

En el caso especifico que mencionas, si solo hay dos elementos y no puedes tocar el html puedes usar "last-of-type" al ser el ultimo elemento, de esta forma:

```css
        li:last-of-type{
            color: red;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="clase-1">
        <div class="clase-2">
            <div class="clase-3">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li>Elemento 1</li>
                    <li>Elemento 2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tambien puedes usar "nth-of-type", al ser el segundo elemento de tipo "li", de esta forma:

```css
        li:nth-of-type(2){
            color: red;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="clase-1">
        <div class="clase-2">
            <div class="clase-3">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li>Elemento 1</li>
                    <li>Elemento 2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Disculpa gracias por tu esfuerzo en tu respuesta, acabo de hacer la edición a mi pregunta, dado que no puedo alterar el html. Estoy modificando un wordpress y el cliente pide no tocar html, solo estilos.

Comment: Entiendo, he modificado la respuesta y he añadido 2 soluciones mas, espero que te puedan ayudar.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!